# Function don't get executed correctly - Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've written some code but its not working as expected. I have the following code:
My Contend View File:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var liste: [Can] = [Can()]
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            liste[0].nested.change()
        } label: {
            Text("\(liste[0].nested.property)")
        }
    }
}
```

and an other file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Can: Identifiable, Equatable, Codable, Hashable {
    
    static func == (lhs: Can, rhs: Can) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    // Jedes Item
    let id = UUID()
    
    var nested = nestedThingies()
    
    struct nestedThingies: Codable {
        var property = 15
        mutating func change(){
            property -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

**What I would expect from this code** is that each time you press the button in `ContentView`, the value of the `nested.property` of the first item in the Array `liste` gets 1 lower (`property -= 1`).

**What's Really Happening:**
The function `change()` gets called, but the value of `property` only changes from 15 to 14 no Mather how often you press that button.

I've tested that code also in a empty Project, and it did the same strange thing...

Can someone explain that behavior to me?
Thanks, Boothosh

Comment: try computed property ``` var id: UUID {
        UUID()
    }```

Comment: What happens if you remove your Equatable conformance?

Comment: @jnpdx That changes nothing :(

Comment: @RajaKishan oh wow that actually worked!! Could you maybe explain why this makes a different?

Comment: I dont know the proper reason. But here you just need Identifiable protocol, remove all other (Equatable, Codable, Hashable) protocol.

Comment: No, my real application is much more complicated xD. I need `Codable` and `Hashable`...

Comment: I’m not in front of a machine, so I can’t test this, but what if the function isn’t mutating and you instead mutate it from the parent level

Comment: You mean that I don't use a function from  `nestedThingies` and instead change the value with  `list[0]. nestedThingies. property  = newValue`? Don't works too :(
Problem is I can't use a computed variable in my case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your implementation of `Equatable`. You're telling the system that the elements are equal if their `id` properties match. But, that's not true -- they are distinctly different if their `nested` values change.

SwiftUI is taking your word for the fact that the elements are the same and doesn't update the UI. I'm not sure why it gets the *first* update right, but it definitely doesn't get the subsequent ones right. To make matters even more strange, if you print the `property` value after it changes, it prints down to `13`, even though the UI stops updating at `14`. My theory is that the erroneous `Equatable` function (`==`) is interfering with the `@State` storage that the system is doing.

If you update your `==` function to reflect the changed `nested` value, it works as expected:

```
struct Can: Identifiable, Equatable, Codable, Hashable {
    
    static func == (lhs: Can, rhs: Can) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.nested.property == rhs.nested.property
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    // Jedes Item
    var id = UUID()
    
    var nested = nestedThingies()
    
    struct nestedThingies: Codable {
        var property = 15
        mutating func change(){
            property -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, your right! I have to change so many things in my app now :/